# "taintedness" vs. "taintness"

Tags: terminology, software-verification, static-analysis

In the context of information flow, when you talk about the property of variables being tainted, do you speak about "taintness" or "taintedness"? Both occur online, both sound weird to me.

An example from http://www-verimag.imag.fr/~potet/PUBLI/mdv10.pdf:

> To achieve that, we propose to perform a taint dependency analysis
>   whose objective will be twofold: 1) to compute the variable taintness
>   at each program location; 2) to extract from the program source the
>   whole dependency chains between each vulnerable statement and the
>   corresponding inputs leading to this vulnerability.

Comment: `-ness` takes an adjective, not a verb, so `taintedness` is correct, `taintness` isn't. Doesn't this rather belong on http://ell.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: I'm puzzled, too.

Answer (score 1):

Which should you use?  Neither.  Personally, I think the words "taintness" and "taintedness" both look awkward.  I would recommend rephrasing the sentence to avoid using either of those words.   Instead, you might try to use something like "whether the variable is tainted".  Or, if you desperately need a noun phrase and can't make the prior suggestion work, try something like "taint status".

For example, I might rewrite the quoted sentence as something like:

> To achieve that, we propose to perform a taint dependency analysis whose objective will be twofold: 1) to compute *which variables are tainted* at each program location; 2) to extract from the program source the whole dependency chains between each vulnerable statement and the corresponding inputs leading to this vulnerability.

(I added italics to highlight the part that I changed.)

Answer (score 0):

- Taintness is how much something taints
- Taintedness is how much something is tainted

I would use taintedness. The variables are the recipient, not the cause, of the tainting/poisoning.